# Parse Substring a string sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column data as below:

```
MASTERDATA-8.009.9.9.1    
CHILDDATA-9.007.1.1.1      
MASTERDATA-2.003.1.1.2
```

I want my output as two columns :

```
COlumn1               Column2           
MASTERDATA.009        8.9.9.1     
CHILDDATA.007        9.1.1.1  
MASTERDATA.003       2.1.1.2
```

Sample Table Script:

```
Create Table ParseData
(
ColumnToParse Varchar(50)
)

Insert into ParseData values('MASTERDATA-8.009.9.9.1')
Insert into ParseData values('CHILDDATA-9.007.1.1.1')
Insert into ParseData values('MASTERDATA-2.003.1.1.2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering all the records are in similar format. Here is one way using string functions

```
SELECT column1 = LEFT(ColumnToParse, Charindex('-', ColumnToParse) - 1)
                 + Substring(ColumnToParse, Charindex('.', ColumnToParse), Charindex('.', ColumnToParse, Charindex('.', ColumnToParse)+1 ) - Charindex('.', ColumnToParse) ),
       column2 = Substring(ColumnToParse, Charindex('-', ColumnToParse)+1, Charindex('.', ColumnToParse) - Charindex('-', ColumnToParse) )
                 + RIGHT(ColumnToParse, Len(ColumnToParse)- Charindex('.', ColumnToParse, Charindex('.', ColumnToParse)+1 ))
FROM   ParseData
```

- **[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/AVOY62566)**

Answer (score 4):

For simple parsing using [**`charindex()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

rextester: http://rextester.com/KYBOZ21026

```
select column1=left(ColumnToParse
                ,charindex('-',ColumnToParse )-1)
              +substring(ColumnToParse
                ,charindex('.',ColumnToParse,charindex('-',ColumnToParse )+1),4)
      ,column2=substring(ColumnToParse,charindex('-',ColumnToParse )+1,1)
                +right(ColumnToParse
                ,len(ColumnToParse )
                 -charindex('.',ColumnToParse,charindex('-',ColumnToParse )+1)-3
                    )
from parsedata
```

results in:

```
+----------------+---------+
|    column1     | column2 |
+----------------+---------+
| MASTERDATA.009 | 8.9.9.1 |
| CHILDDATA.007  | 9.1.1.1 |
| MASTERDATA.003 | 2.1.1.2 |
+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks but i am looking for a different output. If My source COlumn value is MASTERDATA-8.009.9.9.1 ,Then my output should be  MASTERDATA.009 and  8.9.9.1

Comment: Your close, but does not produce the desired output..  Just a tweak would be required

Comment: Just wondering how this answer got 3 upvotes though it does not produce the exact result ;)

Comment: @prdp good question, probably people making the same assumptions as I did without a double take at the question.

Comment: Between am not the downvoter ;) Upvoted now for the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select left(ColumnToParse, CHARINDEX('-', ColumnToParse) ) + 
    substring(columntoparse, CHARINDEX('-', ColumnToParse)+1,5) as Column1
    , right(replace(columntoparse,substring(columntoparse, 
    CHARINDEX('-', ColumnToParse)+2,4),''),7) as Column2
from ParseData
```